# dataLabel in AccumulationChartComponent (pie chart) is not displaying

Tags: reactjs, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I'm trying to build simple pie, doughnut chart in Syncfusion.
And after that I finally managed to display this chart properly, now I can't figure out what is the problem that `dataLabel`'s are not displaying with the chart.

Couldn't find anything in the docs, and even straight up copied examples are not working.

Here is my data sample:

```js
const sample = [
    { name: "label", value: 45, text: "45%"},
    { name: "label1", value: 10, text: "30%"},
    { name: "label2", value: 20, text: "10%"},
    { name: "label3", value: 5, text: "5%"},
  ];
```

Here is the component setup:

```js
      <AccumulationChartComponent 
        id='charts'
        legendSettings={{ visible: true, background: 'white' }}
        height={"500px"}
        width={'500px'}
        background={'transparent'}
      >
        <AccumulationSeriesCollectionDirective>

          <Inject services={[AccumulationLegend, PieSeries, AccumulationDataLabel, AccumulationTooltip]} />

          <AccumulationSeriesDirective 
            dataSource={sample} 
            xName='name' 
            yName='value' 
            innerRadius='40%'

            startAngle={0}
            endAngle={360}
            radius="70%"
            explode
            explodeOffset="10%"
            explodeIndex={2}
            dataLabel={{
              visible: true,
              name: 'name',
              position: 'Outside',
            }}
          >
          </AccumulationSeriesDirective>

        </AccumulationSeriesCollectionDirective>
      </AccumulationChartComponent>
```

Here is how my chart look like right now:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer to that on Syncfusion forum.
`<Inject>` component should be nested in `<AccumulationChartComponent>`.

Moving this line up is the answer in this case:

```js
    <AccumulationChartComponent 
      id='charts'
      legendSettings={{ visible: true, background: 'white' }}
      height={"500px"}
      width={'500px'}
      background={'transparent'}
    >

      <Inject services={[AccumulationLegend, PieSeries, AccumulationDataLabel, AccumulationTooltip]} />

        <AccumulationSeriesCollectionDirective>

          <AccumulationSeriesDirective 
            dataSource={sample} 
            xName='name' 
            yName='value' 
            innerRadius='40%'

            startAngle={0}
            endAngle={360}
            radius="70%"
            explode
            explodeOffset="10%"
            explodeIndex={2}
            dataLabel={{
              visible: true,
              name: 'name',
              position: 'Outside',
            }}
          >
          </AccumulationSeriesDirective>

        </AccumulationSeriesCollectionDirective>
      </AccumulationChartComponent>
```

Details:
https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/176267/datalabel-in-pie-chart-is-not-displayed